# Transferring emails messages from one server to another

Tags: mx-record, email-server, 1and1

My domain example.com is provided by 1&1, but I recently moved my website server from 1&1 to another server, controlled with my cPanel.

I have also been able to set up a user@example.com email account on the new server, but at 1&1 I can still access my old emails with the same user@example.com

I want to transfer those over to the new server - how do I go about doing that? Perferably at no cost. I looked on the web, but couldn't find what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both source and destination servers support IMAP, you can set up one mail client that can see both servers and pretty much drag-and-drop the messages from one server to the other.

Or, for us PINE users, ;A to select all messages in a folder, then AS to apply save-to-folder to all messages, ^T to navigate to the new server, and select the destination folder.  And don't forget to throw a bone to the dinosaur.

Comment: Wow, that was A LOT easier than I was expecting it to be. Did the whole thing in Thunderbird. Email is not exactly my area of experties, I just assume everything is difficult :D  Thanks

Comment: Hey, the win is not mine, but IMAP's - it's explicitly excellent at stuff like that, and much else besides.  I can't understand why people still use POP3 for anything.  Glad you're sorted, and thanks for the prompt feedback.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to go into your home directory, you have access to your mail there and could have downloaded and re-uploaded to the new server's mail location inside the user's folder (after creating accounts on new server).

Example:

```
/home/somedoma/mail/somedomain.com/johnny
```

In this folder, you'll find "new" and "cur", which actually contain the email, but if moving from a cPanel server to another cPanel server, you'd probably be able to just restore the entire "mail" directory containing settings and data for all domains & email addresses.

I realize your answer has already been chosen, but this is a legit way to do your mail backups. In fact, I believe it's how cPanel does migrations itself from its cpmove backup files. Cheers!